# I need to uninstall OpenShot on my Charm PC

Tags: software-installation, openshot

I need to uninstall OpenShot on my Charm PC with Linux. I downloaded OpenShot video editor, but unfortunately it didn't work. Then I got support from the OpenShot team and it worked, but it was so difficult because after downloading the recovery software which they gave me to recover the problem, it opened two OpenShot instances together. Otherwise when I closed and reopened OpenShot it didn't work as it did before. I had to download it with the terminal again to work on OpenShot. Then I thought to uninstall OpenShot from the Charm PC, but I don't know how to uninstall it. Could you help me to uninstall it? Could you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Add to your question by [edit] how you installed `openshot`. That will provide a clue to how to resolve the issue. Don't add to comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?